# Hive Count Performance and Explain indication

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 2 tables.

The first one has an ORC format, with partitions like this : {year,month,day,type} and ~60Millions lines.

The seconde one has TextInputFormat, with partitions like this : {date,type} and ~300Millions lines.

When I do a "SELECT COUNT(*)" on this both tables, the first one gives a result after minutes.

The explain plan being :

```
Plan not optimized by CBO.
Vertex dependency in root stage
Reducer 2 <- Map 1 (SIMPLE_EDGE)
Stage-0
Fetch Operator
limit:-1
Stage-1
Reducer 2 vectorized
File Output Operator [FS_107648]
compressed:true
Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
table:{"serde:":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe","input format:":"org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat","output format:":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"}
Group By Operator [OP_107647]
|  aggregations:["count(VALUE._col0)"]
|  outputColumnNames:["_col0"]
|  Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
|<-Map 1 [SIMPLE_EDGE] vectorized
Reduce Output Operator [RS_107641]
sort order:
Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
value expressions:_col0 (type: bigint)
Group By Operator [OP_107646]
aggregations:["count()"]
outputColumnNames:["_col0"]
Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
Select Operator [OP_107645]
Statistics:Num rows: 64930697 Data size: 158452219904 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
TableScan [TS_107638]
alias:mytable
Statistics:Num rows: 64930697 Data size: 158452219904 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: NONE
```

When I do the same query on the second one, it gives me a result after less 5 seconds...

The explain plan being :

```
Plan not optimized by CBO.
Stage-0
Fetch Operator
limit:1
```

I guess either the partitionning or the format are involved...
Does anyone understand the situation and so, can explain :) it to me ?

Comment: i just have cloned  the "low" table in a new one with in the same table structure (orc, partitions, etc.) and... performances are far better and the explain plan is like the second table... looks like an optimization issue ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are working with `hive.compute.query.using.stats=true`.
Your 2nd query does nothing but fetching the rows count from the metastore

> **hive.compute.query.using.stats**
>   Default Value: false
>   Added In: Hive 0.13.0 with HIVE-5483
>    When set to true Hive will answer a few
>   queries like min, max, and count(1) purely using statistics stored in
>   the metastore. For basic statistics collection, set the configuration
>   property hive.stats.autogather to true. For more advanced statistics
>   collection, run ANALYZE TABLE queries.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Statistics

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But, i queried those tables from my Hive Client without particular option... Why the 2nd will use the metastore and not the 1st ? Is there something to do / to know when creating the table ? When I cloned the "slow" table, I have got a brand new table very fast... So, I think about files organization on HDFS (no fragmentation, a brand new table is up to date, etc.) ?

Comment: **(1)** There is always some configuration. Launch Hive CLI in DEBUG mode (`hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console`) and look for something similar to `... Using hive-site.xml found on CLASSPATH at /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml`  **(2)** No, the only difference is the use of statistics. When you created a the duplicated table you where probably running using `hive.stats.autogather=true` therefore you had statistics that could be used for `select count(*) ...`. Execute `hive.compute.query.using.stats=false` and test again